# 'Cannot create a variadic tuple' error

Tags: swift, xcode6-beta6, dollar.swift

Here's a function from the [Dollar](https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar.swift) framework for Swift:

```
public class func bind<T, E>(function: (T...) -> E, _ parameters: T...) -> (() -> E) {
    return { () -> E in
        typealias TType = (T...)
        return function(unsafeBitCast(parameters, TType.self))
    }
}
```

In the line with the `typealias` I get the `Cannot create a variadic tuple` error. When I remove the braces around `T...` then I receive the `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'` error. So, this is not a solution.

Does anyone know a workaround to get the error away?

This happens since XCode 6 Beta 6, which was (really) released today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the Dollar project now. But for someone who encounters this issue in another project the way to solve it is by doing a unsafeBitCast on the function itself as such which will resolve the compile issue.

```
typealias Function = [T] -> E
let f = unsafeBitCast(function, Function.self)
f(params)
```